# Find the expected number to cross the non-broken bridges?

Tags: probability

There are 10 islands in a line. Two bridges between two consecutive  islands. one is fine, but the other one is broken. If you take the broken bridge, you will fall into water and you have to go back to the start. Start from the first island,find the expected number of time you cross the non-broken bridges when you reach the end.

Comment: Do you 'remember' which bridges are broken and which are good?

Comment: No, the chances are fifty by fifty. randomness involved, that's why they asked you to compute the expectation.

Comment: @paw88789's variation is more interesting, but the chances of crossing all nine bridges assuming they reset each time is 1/512. From that, it should be easy to compute the expected value.

Comment: @barrycarter Doesn't that only give the probability that all 9 unbroken bridges are crossed in the first attempt?

Comment: @Deep If the bridges "reset" each time, as the OP appears to indicate above, that would be the chance each time. The problem paw suggests is more interesting, but, apparently that's not what's being asked.